# Configuration management at scale (100s of modules)

Tags: build, module, configuration-management

What are some clever ideas for doing configuration management of many modules, each with their own trunk/branches/tags?

Maven seems like a great fit for our project, but I wondered what else might be out there...

Answer (score 1):

Check out Ivy, a lighter version of Maven more strictly concerned with CM